# Extreme number of open connections between Web and DB server

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I run 2 servers, 1 web (nginx/php), 1 database (mysql).

Nginx has about 1500 active processes per second, and mysql status shows about 15 currently option connections on average.

Now today i started running: `netstat -npt | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v "ffff\|127\.0\.0\.1" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n`

This showed that there were over 7000 active connections from my webserver to my database server IP. This seems kind of extreme. I do not use persistent connections in PHP to connect to Mysql.

I tried using mysql_close() also, but that seems to make no difference.

On the webserver netstat shows over 7000 connections to the database server

On the database server netstat shows just 300 connections to the web server

Any idea why there are so many open connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking for established connections only:

```
netstat -npt | grep ESTABLISHED | awk ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the status of those connections? I assume it is TIME_WAIT. When you have 1500 req/s, you are opening and closing 1500 TCP connections. And it takes some time to close the connection (there are some timeouts specified in the protocol, so even on localhost the closing is not instant - more info here [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination.htm)).

There is nothing wrong with that - 7000 connections is not much (however persistent connections as mentioned next will be slightly faster). You can have up to 65536 connections between your webserver and database server. Also please note that this isn't your total limit of opened connections as it is usually believed. This limit is not per your IP address, but per IP pair (each pair of src-ip and dst-ip can have 65536 connections among them).

When using nginx, I assume you use PHP in Fast-CGI mode. So for those 1500 req/s, you should have some PHP processes waiting to process them (I have also about 2000-5000 req/s on one of my servers and have 50-250 PHP processes). For such high number of connections and relatively low number of PHP processes, it is better to use persistent connections. Each PHP process will make one permanent connections to the database. So you will have about 100 connections to MySQL, but they will stay opened, so no need to make 3-way TCP handshake & close on each web request.